# Import Blanks as NULL SSIS Expression In Derived Columns

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a ragged right file that I am trying to import where I import a NULL where the value is blank.  I am importing each row into a column called `RowData`, then I am parsing that column into various columns.  I'm using the following expression to do this:

```
TRIM((DT_STR,3,1252)SUBSTRING([RowData],1046,3))== "" 
? (DT_STR,3,1252)NULL(DT_STR,3,1252) 
: (DT_STR,3,1252)SUBSTRING([RowData],1046,3)
```

For some reason, the data type when I try to do this is a Unicode datatype, which is messing up my import.  I am casting both values of the conditional as a non-Unicode.  Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found that we need to cast the entire expression as a non-Unicode string.

```
(DT_STR,3,1252)(TRIM((DT_STR,3,1252)SUBSTRING(RowData,1046,3)) == "" 
? (DT_STR,3,1252)NULL(DT_STR,3,1252) 
: (DT_STR,3,1252)SUBSTRING(RowData,1046,3))
```